# How do I post an ampersand via the Slack hook using Curl?

Tags: curl, slack-api

How do I post an ampersand via the Slack hook with `curl`?

```
$ curl -4 -X POST --data 'payload={"text": "amp;"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/aaa/bbb/ccc
ok

$ curl -4 -X POST --data 'payload={"text": "&amp;"}'
https://hooks.slack.com/services/aaa/bbb/ccc 
invalid_payload

$ curl -4 -X POST --data 'payload={"text": "<>"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/aaa/bbb/ccc
ok

$ curl -4 -X POST --data 'payload={"text": "<&>"}'
https://hooks.slack.com/services/aaa/bbb/ccc 
invalid_payload
```

I am really trying to post something like `Message <https://nagios?host=foo&type=1|link here>` but I can not for the life of me get that `&` accepted.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague figured out that the workaround is to post `%26`:

```
curl -4 -X POST --data 'payload={"text": "%26"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/aaa/bbb/ccc
ok
```

This renders an `&` in Slack and can be used to construct a URL.

Reference: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/2734